# Why is AM-GM giving 2 contradictory results for the same problem?

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

The problem is the following:
given *x* and *y* such that $x+y=1$ and $x,y \geq 0$, find the maximum value of $x^2y$.

The point is, I tried to solve it in 2 different ways, which are shown below, but the second method I used gives a wrong result, and I can't understand where the mistake is.

### First Method

Using AM-GM inequality you can say

$ \displaystyle{\left[{\frac{x}{2}\cdot \frac{x}{2} \cdot y}\right]^{\frac{1}{3}} \leq \frac{\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{2}+y}{3}}$

But we also have

$\displaystyle{\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{2}+y = x+y=1}$

Hence

$\displaystyle{\frac{x^2y}{4} \leq \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3  \quad {\LARGE\Rightarrow} \quad x^2y \leq \frac{4}{27}}$

So the solution is

$ max=\frac{4}{27} $, where $x= \frac {2}{3}$ and $y=\frac{1}{3}$

### Second Method

Using AM-GM inequality again, we have

$ \displaystyle{\left[x\cdot x \cdot y\right]^{\frac{1}{3}} } \leq \frac{x+x+y}{3}$

Now if you substitute $x+y=1$, you get

$\displaystyle{\left[x\cdot x \cdot y\right]^{\frac{1}{3}} } \leq \frac{x+1}{3}$

Cubing both sides of the inequality, it becomes

$\displaystyle {x^2y\leq \frac{(x+1)^3}{27} }$

It follows that $x^2y$ is maximum when it is equal to the other side of the inequality, so we have:

$\displaystyle {x^2y - \frac{(x+1)^3}{27}= 0 }$

As it is given that $x+y =1$, then $ y=1-x$ and we have a cubic equation which is:

$\displaystyle {x^2(1-x) - \frac{(x+1)^3}{27}= 0 }$

I expected that its solution would be $ x= \frac{2}{3} $ as above, but instead, you can check that its only real solution is $x=y=\frac{1}{2}$

Clearly the correct solution is given by the first method that I showed, as it can also be confirmed by looking for the maximum using the derivative. I just don't know why this happens, apparently I don't see any mistake in the second method.

If anyone is able to come up with an explanation, I would appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: Well, given that I got that result using the AM-GM inequality, it does prove that its maximum is $\frac{4}{27}$, as it is always possible the scenario where AM = GM, and in fact it happens when every term is equal to each other, and in the case shown in the problem, exactly when $\frac{x}{2} = y$, and from there you can check that $x^2y$ can indeed be $\frac{4}{27}$, which is its maximum

Comment: In you second method, the equality holds only when $x=y=\frac 1 2.$ If you choose different $x$, the equality will not hold.

Comment: At $x=y=\frac12$, while $x^2y = \frac{(x+1)^3}{27}$, it's possible to have a larger $x^2y$ with a different $x$, because that $\frac{(x+1)^3}{27}$ bound is not a constant but an increasing bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in this assumption in your second approach:

> It follows that $x^2y$ is maximum when it is equal to the other side of the inequality

This is not true; while at $x = \frac12$,

$$x^2y = \frac{(x+1)^3}{27},$$

the right-hand side is not a constant upper bound, but increasing.

Then it turns out (from the first approach) that the maximum value of $x^2y$ is at $x=\frac23$, when the right-hand side upper bound is larger than the value of $x^2y$.

The [graph of the two sides of the (in)equality](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+x%5E2%281-x%29%3B+y+%3D+%28x%2B1%29%5E3%2F27+from+x%3D0+to+x%3D1) demonstrates better than my words.

---

From just the condition $0\le x \le 1$ and the inequality

$$x^2y \le \frac{(x+1)^3}{27},$$

the right-hand side has the global maximum $\frac 8{27}$ at $x=1$, so a rough constant upper bound from these would be

$$x^2y \le \frac{(x+1)^3}{27} \le \frac{8}{27}.$$

But the two equalities happen at different $x$, so overall it's a strict inequality

$$x^2y < \frac{8}{27}$$

and $\frac{8}{27}$ is not the maximum value of $x^2y$.

Comment: Thanks, I now understand more clearly where the problem is. Though, I don’t understand why this happens, I mean, GM’s maximum is always equal to AM, so if the GM has a maximum for $x=a$, then for $x=a$ $AM = GM$.
Or maybe is it that this property doesn’t hold when both sides of the inequality are variable?

Comment: @Ale18V the implication from $GM\le AM$ is that when $x \ne 1/2$, $x^2y < \frac{(x+1)^3}{27}$. But as the RHS is increasing, it's the case here that $x^2y$ would achieve a larger value for some $x > 1/2$. Maybe [a graph of the inequality](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+x%5E2%281-x%29%3B+y+%3D+%28x%2B1%29%5E3%2F27+from+x%3D0+to+x%3D1) would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, you cleared my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

By your second way the equality occurs for $x=y=\frac{1}{2}$, which  gives $x^2y\leq\frac{1}{8},$ which is indeed the maximal value for $x=y$.

But why does $x=y$?

Maybe for $x\neq y$ we can get a greater value?

And indeed, your first solution does not depend on the assuming $x=y$ and it gives a right answer.

Comment: Yes, I don’t understand either: $ x = y = \frac { 1}{2} $ would be the maximum of $xy$, but not $ x^2y$.

Comment: @Ale18V See please better your post. You wrote $\sqrt[3]{x^2y}\leq\frac{x+x+y}{3}$. It's AM-GM and  the equality in this inequality occurs for $x=x=y$, id est, for $x=y$, which with $x+y=1$ gives $x=y=\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: Yes, I'll edit right now, i don't know why desmos gave as only solution some negative value of x